# Threading.Sleep with System.Threading.Tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

what happens if i put a System.Threading.Thread.Sleep() into a Task that is started with TaskFactory.StartNew()?
Does it put the executing Thread itself to sleep or will this Thread execute another Task while the first one Sleeps?

I`m asking this because I´m currently working on a Server which must sometimes wait to receive data from its clients, and if I put the Task asleep, which is handling the client-connection, I would like to know if the Thread that executes this specific Task is then able to Handle another connection while the first one waits for data.

Comment: I dont know exactly what you are trying to achieve, but IMO you should rethink your design. Starting a Task in order to make it sleep sounds not an optimal solution for me. For long running operations ( including any sleep) consider using a Thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Thread.Sleep` *always* make the currently executed thread sleep, whether that thread is executing a task or not.

There's no concept of a *task* sleeping - only a thread. Of course the thread pool will allow multiple threads to execute, so you'll probably just end up with more threads than you really need.

It sounds like you may want to wait for the data asynchronously, continuing with the rest of the work for the task when that data is available.

C# 5's async methods will make all of this a *lot* simpler.